# AlphaFold on VertexAI - Stuck in setting up notebook for 2 hours

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to run AlphaFold on VertexAI as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/running-alphafold-on-vertexai). However, my instance creation is stuck in this state for roughly two hours now. There is no error message either. I am wondering if something has gone wrong or this is just the expected time it will take to setup a new instance?

I actually tried with two different notebooks. One is the [default one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/raw/main/community-content/alphafold_on_workbench/AlphaFold.ipynb) linked in the above article and the other is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deepmind/alphafold/main/notebooks/AlphaFold.ipynb

Both are in the same state for roughly the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and Canceled the notebook creation. When I went back to the Workbench screen, THEN it displayed me this error message:

[image]

So, turns out that the new Google Cloud account I created has no quota for GPUs. In order to increase the quota, I first had to upgrade to a full GCP account. And now I need to update for a couple of days before I can actually request the quota increase because I got this automated response when I submitted the quota increase request.

[image]

I have also contacted Sales on the link given at the end of this email to see if they can escalate the process in any way.

Comment: You need to wait until the sales teams approve the GPU quota into your project since there’s not much that can be made without the GPU.

Comment: Did you get any answer from support?

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz Yeah, a sales rep finally contacted me on Friday (Feb 4) and asked to schedule a call with them. I scheduled for Monday (7th Feb) using her calendar but she declined the invite mentioning that she is on vacation until 14th Feb. So now I have scheduled another call on Feb 15th. Let's see how it goes.
Although there is no meeting link in the calendar invite, so I am not sure how exactly we are going to meet. Hopefully she will send a link before meeting.